# enabling gaze only for mobile VR mode

Tags: javascript, aframe, webvr

I need to enable the **gaze** only for the **mobileVR** mode in A-Frame these is the code I have tried but not working properly can any one please help me to solve this error please.

```js
var cursorEl = document.querySelector('a-cursor');
if (!AFRAME.utils.device.isMobile()) 
{              
document.querySelector('a-scene').addEventListener('enter-vr', function () 
{
cursorEl.parentEl.removeChild(cursorEl);
}
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add/remove the cursor with a component attached to the camera:

```
let cursor = document.createElement('a-cursor');
this.el.sceneEl.addEventListener('enter-vr', function() {
   el.appendChild(cursor);
})
this.el.sceneEl.addEventListener('exit-vr', function() {
   el.removeChild(cursor);
})
```

You can see how it works here: https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/5uq1vmym/;

---

If You want to make it exclusive for mobile, as far as i see the  `AFRAME.utils.device.isMobile()` method is working properly, so You could just wrap the listeners in a check:

```
if(AFRAME.utils.device.isMobile()){ //addListeners }
```

Comment: I need the cursor only for mobile VR mode for desktop and mobile I am using click and touch control

Comment: @KumareshR Then i would wrap the listeners in a check as described :) when not on mobile, the enter/exit vr listeners won't apply.

Comment: @KumareshR if You add camera references(document.querySelector('a-camera')) instead of 'this.el'/'el', it should be working, as long as the script is in the head tag, otherwise it can do unexpected things. feel free to mess around with the fiddle

Comment: This is how I added the curosr can u please make changes over here it'll be very helpful to me thanks

Comment: @KumareshR If it needs to be removed/added, You need to hold a reference to it in the script. Either add the components to the cursor like i did here: https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/5uq1vmym/2/ ( check out how i added the event_set_1 to the cursor ), or You can clone your cursor ( using cloneNode() ), keep it as a reference, and remove the original entity.

Comment: @KumareshR try setting the cursor attributes in js, check the code on the bottom https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/e0w297f9/16/

Comment: here what is the need for create element we define the <a-cursor> already in the aframe scene right?  let cursor = document.createElement('a-cursor');

Comment: You can't have the element on scene all the time. Making visible=false; only prevents the rendering, it will still click on objects. Thats why imo You should make it in js, or clone it and remove the original from the scene.